# expandable list - change images displayed when expanded \ closed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of expandable drop-down tabs using the ToggleList javascript function below. When the tab is closed I would like to display expand.png and when it's open I would like to display close.png. Right now Any help would be appreciated.

The code below expands\minimizes the dropdown tabs, but is not switching the png files.

**Full javascript + html:**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

            function ToggleList(IDS) {
              HideRange('ulist','div',IDS);  // not required unless using 'HideRange()' below

              var CState = document.getElementById(IDS);
              if (CState.style.display != "block") { CState.style.display = "block";      }
                                              else { CState.style.display = "none";   }
              // get a reference to the image contained in the <a> that was just clicked
              var img = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
              // switch the graphic, if it's expand set it to collapse, otherwise expand
              img.src = img.src == "expand.png" ? "minimize.png" : "expand.png";
            }

            function HideRange(sect,elTag,IDS) {
                  var ContentObj = document.getElementById(sect);
                  var AllContentDivs = ContentObj.getElementsByTagName(elTag);

                }


                </script>


                <ul id="ulist">
                <li><a href="#expand" onclick="ToggleList('expand0')"><p><img src="expand.png"/> Subject</p></a></li>
                <div id="expand0" class="divInfo">Text</div>

                <li><a href="#expand" onclick="ToggleList('expand1')"><p><img src="expand.png"/> Subject</p></a></li>
                <div id="expand1" class="divInfo">Text</div>

                <li><a href="#expand" onclick="ToggleList('expand3')"><p><img src="expand.png"/> Subject</p></a></li>
                <div id="expand3" class="divInfo">Text</div>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to implement that - comments in the code

```
    function ToggleList(IDS) {
      HideRange('ulist','div',IDS);  // not required unless using 'HideRange()' below
      var CState = document.getElementById(IDS);
      if (CState.style.display != "block") { CState.style.display = "block";      }
                                      else { CState.style.display = "none";   }
      // get a reference to the image contained in the <a> that was just clicked
      var img = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
      // switch the graphic, if it's expand set it to collapse, otherwise expand
      img.src = img.src == "img/expand.png" ? "img/collapse.png" : "img/expand.png";
    }
```

Comment: There must be a syntax error somewhere. The tabs no longer expand\minimize.

Comment: If only there was a way to see syntax errors!  (Check the console)

Comment: I separated the code and put it in a separate html file. https://pastebin.com/rwjcgbjp is what I'm using now. The tabs are collapsing + minimizing now, but the images (expand and collapse) still aren't changing. It always remains expand.png

Comment: Before I update please [take a look](https://jsfiddle.net/aj176dfd/) and let me know.